# Extract Chunk of data from 2D Array

Tags: c, queue

I am using a queue to store real time incoming data packets from remote sensor node. Queue looks like this.

```
    unsigned char aRxBuf[100]; //Buffer to receive incoming packet

    typedef struct  queue
    {
     unsigned char front;   
     unsigned char rear;    
     unsigned char Rx_buffer[5][128]; //Buffer to store incoming packets 
   }QUEUE;

  Queue rx_queue;
```

Each time when packet arrives I will insert in to a queue.

```
  in_queue(aRxBuf);
```

Also each time I am storing incoming packets (ie.aRxBuf) in to one of the row in the multidimensional array. I am also extracting few chunks data from multidimensional array Rx_Buffer. For example RX_PACKET_LENGTH will be reside in those indexes and it is always fixed. Hence it is easy to extract using following way.

```
  #define RX_PACKET_LENGTH   (rx_queue.Rx_buffer[rx_queue.front][2]<<8 | rx_queue.Rx_buffer[rx_queue.front][3])
```

Now my problem is, I need to extract some part of data whose size is always varying. That is If I want to extract data from Rx_buffer whose starting index is 15 always, but ending index is always varying. Let me say for example

```
  rx_queue.Rx_buffer[rx_queue.front][15])
  to
  rx_queue.Rx_buffer[rx_queue.front][30])
```

or

```
 rx_queue.Rx_buffer[rx_queue.front][15])
  to
  rx_queue.Rx_buffer[rx_queue.front][44])
```

How can I extract these chunks of data?

Comment: shifting a char 8 bits left will result in 0x00.  that calculation/#define statement needs to have each of the two characters cast to 'int' (or at least to 'short')  Otherwise, it will not work

Comment: do u know the size to be copied(ie, varying size in each time)? or there is any start or stop bits?. If yes you can store it easily. Other wise its difficult. In such case u can use max length copying.

Comment: a struct definition should not be typedef'd  typedef'ing the array only cutters the code, can (and usually does) lead to mis-understandings, and clutters the compiler name space.  should give the struct definition a tag name, then always refer to the struct type as 'struct tagname'

Comment: @JissJ . Yes I know the size to be copied. Can you please tell me what is exactly max length copying.

Comment: Then why can't you use **memcpy**?. like **memcpy(ur_dst_addr,&rx_queue.Rx_buffer[rx_queue.front][start_index]),size_tobe_stored)**. Use destination address as **char*** same as data type used in queue.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to create an array of the MAX LENGTH that the data can be.

Then create a pointer to char and set it to 
&( rx_queue.Rx_buffer[rx_queue.front][15])

then call the memcpy() function,

giving the current length to copy as the third parameter –